# Linq Count is returning different results

Tags: linq, ado.net

I have a datatable that has two rows with a few columns, one of which is ABC. I have verified the data rows do exist and all values are set correctly but the two lines below produce different results:

```
            //r3 =1
            var r3 = dt.Select().Where(o => o["ABC"] == cls).Count();

            //r4 =2 (correct)
            var r4 = dt.Select().Count(o => o["ABC"].Equals(cls));
```

It was just a fluke that I tried the second option but surely these should do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.Equals` not `Object.ReferenceEquals`(`==` operator on object):

```
int count = dt.AsEnumerable().Count(r => r.Field<string>("ABC") == cls);
```

Here is a sample which demonstrates this issue and also shows when string interning circumvents it.

Testtable:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ABC");
dt.Rows.Add("Test");
dt.Rows.Add("Test");  // note that C# is case sensitive, maybe this is another issue
dt.Rows.Add("test");
```

The first string [is interned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned(v=vs.110).aspx) since it is a string literal, so it is reused from the already available string in the pool. The second string is created using the string constructor which doesn't use the [string pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

```
string cls1 = "test";   // uses string pool
string cls2 = new string("test".ToCharArray()); // skips pool
int count = dt.AsEnumerable().Count(r => r.Field<string>("ABC") == cls2); // 1
count =  dt.Select().Where(o => o["ABC"] == cls1).Count();  // 1
count = dt.Select().Where(o => o["ABC"] == cls2).Count();   // 0
```

So both should be strings if you use `==` to compare strings.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that is very obscure behaviour.